# Finding Cyclic Codes from monic divisors of $x^n-1$ (Coding Theory)

Tags: coding-theory

I'm reading San Ling, Chaoping Xing 's Coding theory-A first course, Section 7.2.; in particular, p.140, Example 7.2.15

First, let me introduce the definition of cyclic code

Def.1. A cyclic code $C$ in $\mathbf{F}_q^n$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbf{F}_q^n$ such that if $(a_0, a_1, \dots ,a_{n-1}) \in C$, then $(a_{n-1}, a_0, \dots ,a_{n-2}) \in C$

Second. let's see the next images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm now trying to understand the below squared equality. By the Theorem 7.2.8., since $g(x):=(1+x)(1+x^2+x^3)$ divides $x^7-1$, it is a generator polynomial of some cyclic code in $\mathbf{F}_2^{7}$
(a generator polynomial of cyclic code $C \subseteq \mathbf{F}_q^{n}$ means the generator polynomial of $
\pi(C)$, where $\pi : \mathbf{F}_q^{n} \to \mathbf{F}_q[x]/(x^n-1)$ is defined as the above image (7.1).)

But why the squared equality is true? ; i.e., how can we find/exhibits the cyclic code explicitly associated with the generator polynomial $(1+x)(1+x^2+x^3)$ ? Is there such an algorithm? Can we explain more in detail?

**Edit**. One possible strategy ; Since the degree of $g(x) := (1+x)(1+x^2+x^3)$ is 4, by the above theorem 7.2.14, the corresponding cyclic code $C_g := \pi^{-1}(<g(x)>)$ has dimension 7-4=3. Since we are working over binary code ($\mathbf{F_2}$), the cyclic code $C_g$ has cardinality $2^3=8$.

Now the $g(x):=(1+x)(1+x^2+x^3)$ corresponds to $(1,1,1,0,1,0,0) \in \mathbf{F}_2^7$ under the $\pi^{-1}$. Applying the cyclicity condition we introduced in the above definition, {000000, 1110100, 0111010, 0011101, 1001110, 0100111, 1010011, 1101001} are in the $C_g$. So the equality is true

**Now, Let me propose a further question** : Let $g(x)$ be a monic polynomial of degree $d$ dividing $x^n-1 \in \mathbf{F}_{q}[x]$ and $C_{g} : = \pi^{-1}(<g(x)>)$ be the corresponding cyclic code. By the above theorem 7.2.14, $|C_{g}| = q^{n-d}$, as the above argument.

Let $c:=\pi^{-1}(g(x)) \in C_{g} \subseteq \mathbf{F}_{q}^n$ be the codeword corresponding to $g(x)$. Let $S_c$ be the set of all cyclic shifts of the $c$, which is also contained in the $C_{g}$ by the definition of cyclic code.

And,

Q. If the cardinality $|S_c|$ is less than $q^{n-d} -1$, how can we find the remaining elements in the $C_{g} - S_c$? Is there somewhat effective algorithm for finding such elements? related analysis/theorem?

C.f. For example (similar question)  (his book p.139) :

[image]

In the above example, for $g(x):= (1+x+x^2)^{2}$,  $|C_g| = 2^{6-4} =4 $. And $S_c$ (as above) = {101010, 010101}. Luckily, we find that $(1+x)g(x) = 1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+x^5 \in <g(x)>$, which corresponds to $(1,1,1,1,1,1)$ under the $\pi^{-1}$. But if the cardinality $|C_g|$ becomes larger and larger, it seems to be more difficult to find the elements in $C_g - S_{c}$. How can we  deal with this issue? Perhaps..is there a somewhat systematic approach to solve this problem ?

Anyone helps?

Comment: You get all the $q^{n-d}$ codewords as $\Bbb{F}_q$-linear combinations of $g(x)$, $xg(x)$,$\ldots$,$x^{n-d-1}g(x)$. All those polynomials have degrees $<n$ so they won't wrap around. In other words, a cyclic code is also assumed to be linear.

Comment: O.K. I found the related theorem in his book, Theorem 7.3.1. Uhm..Amount of work needed for finding is significantly reduced. Thanks for simple and valuable comment !